# Using more widget in main page cause slow loading Wordpress?

Tags: widgets

I'm using a custom widget in homepage and I use this widget almost 20 times in main page. Whether it is about slow loading site?!
http://akhbartop.ir/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like server response time and stylesheet loading are causing the greatest delay:

[image]

[image]

You can measure the network performance of your site yourself using the Network panel in Chrome: Right click > Inspect > Network (refresh the page to load details)

Comment: so what do you suggest to improve my loading website?!

Comment: Initial connection is 235.92 ms. Check with your hosting provider why.

Comment: so you mean the real problem is from server not script?!

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-javascripts-to-the-bottom-or-footer-in-wordpress/) may help you in reducing your loading time. And speed up your website. I this you should try using some cache plugin.

Comment: im using wp rocket plugin.do you think should checked this option in wp rocket setting? " Enable caching for WordPress feeds."

Comment: En-queuing scripts in the footer will improve a lot. Caching plugins will help you achieve extra mile. I am not aware of that plugin. Go through the documentation of the plugin.